# ERROR TypeError: array.map is not a function in angular pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-pipe

I am getting this error ERROR TypeError: ERROR TypeError: array.map is not a function error while using this angular pipe and here is the code.

```js
export class CharacterWithCommasPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array) {
    return array.map(item => item.name).join(', ');
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also post the view code that uses this pipe, you most likely hand something into the pipe that is not an array

Comment: Objects, {}, in JavaScript does not have the method .map(). so please make sure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are not calling this pipe on an array.

You should ideally make sure that you throw an error if the `input` to the pipe is not in the expected format. That way it would be implemented in a more elegant way

Make the following changes to your pipe in order to do so:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "joiner"
})
export class JoinerPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arrayToJoin: Array<any>, joinBy?: string) {
    if (arrayToJoin && arrayToJoin.map) {
      return arrayToJoin.map(item => item.name).join(joinBy || ", ");
    }
    throw new Error('joiner pipe only expects an Array as a first argument');
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<p> With Joiner Value - {{ items | joiner: ' and ' }}</p>
<p> Without Joiner Value - {{ items | joiner }}</p>

<p> With wrong Input that throws error on the console - {{ someOtherItems | joiner: ', ' }}</p>
```

On a data that looks something like this:

```
items = [
  { name: 'A' },
  { name: 'B' },
  { name: 'C' },
  { name: 'D' }
];

someOtherItems = 'ABCD';
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-should-throw-an-error?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.